# Activiti REST API / Get a specific user by Id

Tags: rest, activiti

I am trying to get a specific user data from Activiti based on the Id.

The below end-point is not working for me:

```
/enterprise/users/{userId}
```

I receive the following resonse:

```
{"message":"Can only get user details for authenticated user","messageKey":"GENERAL.ERROR.FORBIDDEN"}
```

Is there a way?

Thank you in advance for your feedbacks.

Comment: Is the userId authonticated to access the API ?

Comment: The authentification is done. I only get a response when I put the authentified userId in the query. If I put another userId, I get the response shown above

Answer (score 0):

The user authenticated must have privilege(access) to view other users this is generally an `admin user`. otherwise no user can view other user's profile even if they are put in the same group. see [userguide](https://docs.alfresco.com/process-services1.8/topics/users.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please find below my current situation:
/enterprise/users?externalId=abc is working fine
/enterprise/users?filter=abc is also working fine
I need to find a way to filter users using the main Id